# T-SQL Query to show records side by side

Tags: t-sql, pivot-table

I have some records in the database that looks like the below

| Company | Contract No | Gender | Month |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITV | cont1 | male | aug |  |  |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | male | feb |  |  |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | female | jan |  |  |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | male | dec |  |  |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | female | apr |  |  |  |  |  |
| C4 | cont1 | male | sept |  |  |  |  |  |

Separately the data looks like this
Male Records:

| Company | Contract No | Gender | Month |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITV | cont1 | male | aug |  |  |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | male | feb |  |  |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | male | dec |  |  |  |  |  |
| C4 | cont1 | male | sept |  |  |  |  |  |

Female Records

| Company | Contract No | Gender | Month |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITV | cont1 | female | jan |  |  |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | female | apr |  |  |  |  |  |

I'm trying to get the data to look like this, i.e side by side for the same company, Contract No without a cartesian / cross join.

| Company | Contract No | Male Gender | Male Month | Female Gender | Female Month |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITV | cont1 | male | aug | female | jan |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | male | feb | female | apr |  |  |  |
| ITV | cont1 | male | dec | null | null |  |  |  |
| C4 | cont1 | male | sept | null | null |  |  |  |

What am I missing please?

Comment: *"What am I missing please?"* Your attempt and a description of the logic; you forgot to include both in the post. You don't, for example, explain why Male|Aug is related to Female|Jan for ITV.

Answer (score 0):

The idea you are looking for is a FULL OUTER JOIN. It can be implement like below. But you should think more careful about your data model and what you want to do. FULL OUTER JOIN can be useful in some other context.

```
SELECT COALESCE( MaleRecords.Company, FemaleRecords.Company) Company
, COALESCE(MaleRecords.ContractNo, FemaleRecords.ContractNo ) ContractNo
, MaleRecords.Gender MaleGender
, MaleRecords.Month  MaleMonth
, FemaleRecords.Gender FemaleGender
, FemaleRecords.Month  FemaleMonth
, ...
FROM (
  SELECT Company, ContractNo, Gender, Month, ...
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company, ContractNo ORDER BY Month) RowNumber
  FROM <Table>
  WHERE Gender = 'male'
  ) MaleRecords
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT Company, ContractNo, Gender, Month, ...
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company, ContractNo ORDER BY Month) RowNumber
  FROM <Table>
  WHERE Gender = 'female'
  ) FemaleRecords
  on MaleRecords.Company = FemaleRecords.Company
  and MaleRecords.ContractNo = FemaleRecords.ContractNo
  and MaleRecords.RowNumber = FemaleRecords.RowNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
  select Company, ContractNo, Gender, Month, row_number() over (partition by Company,ContractNo,Gender 
  order by case 
       when Month='jan' then 1
       when Month='feb' then 2
       when Month='mar' then 3
       when Month='apr' then 4
       when Month='may' then 5
       when Month='jun' then 6
       when Month='jul' then 7
       when Month='aug' then 8
       when Month='sep' then 9
       when Month='nov' then 10
       when Month='oct' then 11
       when Month='dec' then 12
       end
      ) as RowNo
from myTable),
  maleData as (select Company, ContractNo, Gender, Month, RowNo 
      from data 
      where Gender = 'male'),
  femaleData as (select Company, ContractNo, Gender, Month, RowNo 
      from data
      where Gender = 'female')
select coalesce(m.Company, f.Company) Company,
  coalesce(m.ContractNo, f.ContractNo) ContractNo,
  m.Gender MaleGender, 
  m.Month MaleMont,
  f.Gender FemaleGender, 
  f.Month FemaleMonth
from maleData m
  full join femaleData f on m.Company = f.Company and
    m.ContractNo = f.ContractNo and
    m.RowNo = f.RowNo;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/K3XuLOvK)